# Unable to bind thymeleaf template and spring boot correctly

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am working on registration in spring boot with spring security and thymeleaf but for some reason the `userForm.getUsername()` gives null value during POST (see code below)

**Person.java**

```
@Entity@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id@Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "mobile")
    private String mobile;

    @JsonIgnore@Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Transient@JsonIgnore
    private String passwordConfirm;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)@JoinTable(name = "bookandperson", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "username"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bookName"))
    private List < Book > listOfBooks = new ArrayList < Book > ();
}
```

**PersonController.java**

```
@Controller
public class PersonController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;

@Autowired
private UserValidator userValidator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registration(Model model, Principal user) {
    if (user != null) {
        return "redirect:/";
    }
    model.addAttribute("userForm", new Person());

    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute Person userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    System.out.println(userForm.getUsername()); //This is giving null value
    userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("binding result has errors");
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.save(userForm);

    securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

**registration.html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <nav th:replace="common/navbar :: common-navbar"/>

    <div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
    <form th:action="@{/registration}" method="post">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputUsername" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Username</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="${userForm.username}" id="inputUsername" value="" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="mobile" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Mobile</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="${userForm.mobile}" id="inputMobile" placeholder="Mobile">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" th:field="${userForm.password}" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="inputPasswordConfirm" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" th:field="${userForm.passwordConfirm}" id="inputPasswordConfirm" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
       <div class="offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
       </div>
       </div>

       <small th:text="${error}"></small>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

I binded correctly using `th:field="${userForm.username}"` but unable to find what is the problem here.

Comment: Just to make sure you do have setters in your `Person` class right? To be more specific the method `setUsername`

Comment: @Ranjeet Thank you so much! I changed the field `personName` to `username` but did not update `setPersonName` to `setusername`. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

you have to take the model object into the form as follows

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/registration}" th:object="${userForm}" method="post">
```

and add the getters and setters to the Person class